# How I query (with mysql) column names that "unfortunately" have round brackets?

Tags: mysql

If I query like this `SELECT column_Name_(example) FROM primarytable WHERE blablabla` an exception occurs while debugging.

Is there a way to specify that in a certain column all the char are only a string?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The method that you all told me doesn't work!
In particular: if I query "SELECT 'something(hello)' FROM somewhere" I receive all rows with the name of "something(hello)" not all the rows with something(hello) VALUE.
How can i fix this? 
Ps. can you tell me moreover how i format the code? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `` ` ``:

```
SELECT `column_Name_(example)` FROM primarytable WHERE blablabla
```

or, depending on the SQL mode, `"`:

```
SELECT "column_Name_(example)" FROM primarytable WHERE blablabla
```

Comment: Not single quotes. Only double-quotes or back-quotes.

Comment: No single quotes and no double quotes;) Only backticks

Comment: @nicogawenda Depending on the SQL mode, `"` are possible as well.

Comment: Double quotes can be used if [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is enabled.

Comment: Good to know, you should add this to the initial comment:)

Comment: One can use both as told by @glglgl depends on SQL Mode :)

Comment: @viny Your answer is still wrong. You can't use single quotes as column name delimiter.

Comment: @ypercube I am not an expert of using MySql, but have you ever tried single quote?

Answer (score 7):

You use backticks to [delimit non-standard identifiers in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

```
SELECT `column_Name_(example)` FROM `primarytable` WHERE blablabla
```

Note the difference (after comment)

```
`    correct, backtick
'    not correct, single quote = string delimiter
```

Comment: The method that you all told me doesn't work! In particular: if I query "SELECT 'something(hello)' FROM somewhere" I receive all rows with the name of "something(hello)" not all the rows with something(hello) VALUE. How can i fix this? Ps. can you tell me moreover how i format the code? thanks!

Comment: I use backticks not single quotes

Comment: @user2424743: please accept this answer then with the tick on the left

Answer (score 2):

Like this, with backticks:

```
SELECT `column_Name_(example)` FROM primarytable WHERE blablabla
```